# Парадокс: при определенном коде чем выше приоритет процесса, тем дольше будет выполняться программа

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ос

Причем разница огромная, вплоть до 10 раз!

На 4-ехядерном процессоре нижеприведенная программа при низком проиритете процесса выполняется от 800 мс до 1600, в то время как при высоком - не было меньше 9 секунд

Как объяснить это неожидаемое поведение?

PS. Приоритет менял в диспетчере задач, проверял много раз в Release-конфигурации без VS, Windows 10

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace LoadTest
{
    class Test
    {
        const int n = 1000;
        static int count = 0;
        const int stepCount = 10;
        static AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static AutoResetEvent areEnd = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                char action = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                switch (action)
                {
                    case 't': Threads(); break;
                }
                are.Reset();
                mre.Reset();
                areEnd.Reset();
            }
        }

        static void Threads()
        {
            Thread[] ts = new Thread[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                ts[i] = new Thread(CPU);
                ts[i].Start();
            }

            are.WaitOne();//все потоки готовы
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            mre.Set();//начать расчет
            areEnd.WaitOne();//расчет окончен
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        static void CPU(object i)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            if (count == n) are.Set();//оповещаем что все потоки созданы

            mre.WaitOne();//ждем создания всех потоков

            Simple();

            Interlocked.Decrement(ref count);
            if (count == 0) areEnd.Set();//оповещаем о завершении всех потоков
        }

        static void Simple()
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < stepCount; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подозреваю что затык в планировщике Windows

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, мне вот кажется, что надо копать в сторону "много потоков выводят на одну консоль"

Comment: если дело касается реал-тайма, то есть такое в книге Windows Internals: Be aware that many important Windows kernel-mode system threads run in the real-time priority range, so if threads spend excessive time running in this range, they might block critical system functions (such as in the memory manager, cache manager, or other device drivers). Из-за чего программа плодящая много потоков с приоритетом реал-тайм может работать *медленнее*, поскольку она все эфирное время у системных потоков занимает. Но это догадки.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, просто не думаю, что я этим кодом запускаю эти самые "important Windows kernel-mode system threads"

Comment: @Quitrix там не написано, что ты их запускаешь. Там написано, что системные потоки работают в режиме реалтайм. Если запустить процесс в вопросе в режиме реалтайм, то все его потоки будут работать с приоритетом реалтайм, и эти потоки *могут* помешать работе системных функций Windows, что вызовет падение производительности.

Comment: Увеличени приоритета приводит к более частому переключению контекста потоков, как раз на порядок где-то, т.е. часть времени уходит на планирование и переключение потоков.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, не, не запускаю в приоритете "реалтайм", высокого или даже нормального хватает, чтоб увидеть разницу) Да и если я перепишу код на последовательный вывод, а не параллельный, то разницы не будет, так что не думаю, что проблема в этом

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, насколько я знаю, переключение контекста более глобальная величина (влияет на все процессы) и достаточно фиксированная (на серверных win - 50 раз в секунду, на домашних - 64, хотя есть возможность изменить и всякие программы для работы с мультимедиа меняют на 1000 раз в секунду). В поддержу моей теории - переключение контекста вроде как реализовано через спец. таймер.
А приоритет меняет количество цп-времени

Comment: Console.WriteLine всегда синхронный. Сама Console это отдельный процесс, дочерний от вашего. Для начала ему вы приоритет не повышаете. Далее, множество ваших потоков, в попытке синхронизироваться, вызывают объекты ядра системы, которые и так то медленные, но в вашем случае ещё более замедлены изза повышенного приоритета вашего процесса.

Comment: @ИванК, а почему объекты ядра еще более замедляются, если я повышаю приоритет процесса?

Comment: @Qutrix потому что они не часть вашего процесса, и повышая приоритет своему процессу, вы оставляете меньше времени другим процессам. Попробуйте написать не блокирующий код, и я уверен вы получите прирост производительности вместо падения.

Comment: Чтобы понять как написать неблокирующий код, советую почитать Рихтера, последнее издание по net 4.5 главы про асинхронность.

Comment: @ИванК, "Сама Console это отдельный процесс, дочерний от вашего" - разве? какой же это процесс, если не мой?

Comment: Не знаю как картинку выложить, тут скрин: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/9/14/c4f44e4617b2d781be0947391aa8c5c4-full.png

Comment: @ИванК, и правда) но вот к чему я еще придерусь: "потому что они не часть вашего процесса, и повышая приоритет своему процессу, вы оставляете меньше времени другим процессам" - когда мой процесс блокируется - ему не выделяется время цп. То есть когда я увеличиваю приоритет своего процесса -> он быстрее выполняется -> быстрее доходит до блокировки -> быстрее начнет выполнятся не мой процесс. Разве нет?